# How to use Variable Argument Lists without using operator

Tags: c

I'm looking for a way to be able to use Variable Argument list without the need to use operator

Code example:

```
 void list_test(int index, ...) {
    va_list va;
    va_start(va, index);

    if (isInt()) {
        int *var = va_arg(va, int*);
        *var = GetNumber(index);
    }
    else if (isBool()) {
        bool* var = va_arg(va, bool*);
        *var = GetEnable(index);
    }
    va_end(va);
 }
```

So I use it as follows:

```
list_test(0, &var_int, &var_bool);
```

Is there a way to do this without using the `&` operator?

Would it be possible to use `va_copy`?

Comment: This is a "why doesn't the language work the way I want it to" question. The only answer possible is "because that is how it is."

Answer (score 2):

Your issue has nothing to do with variadic arguments.

All arguments in C are pass by value, so if you want a function to modify a variable from the calling function, you have to pass that variable's address to the function.

So `list_test` needs to take pointers as arguments to modify what the pointers  point to, whether those arguments are variadic or not.